# Combining Pandas Dataframe with Numpy Arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an array of arrays that I want to combine with a data frame.

```
arrays=[np.array(i) for i in [[1,2],[5,6,7],[]]] #let me illustrate the arrays like this

df=pd.DataFrame({'Col':['x','y','z']})
```

Each array element corresponds to a row in the df. 
This is my desired output:

[image: ht]

Here is a way you could duplicate the df rows to accomodate the array elements going in:

```
df.loc[df.index.repeat([max(1,len(i)) for i in arrays])]
```

Thank you

Comment: Make a dataframe from the array.  I believe pandas has many ways of joining frames.

Comment: I thought about that but I get the array elements listed within each row of that dataframe. I couldn't figure out how to stack them vertically into more rows.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic]. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

arrays = [np.array(i) for i in [[1, 2], [5, 6, 7], []]]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['x', 'y', 'z']})

# this creates a mesh (cross-product) Dataframe
mesh = pd.DataFrame([pair for co in zip(df['Col'], arrays) for pair in product(*co)],
                    columns=['Col', 'n'])

# merge with the original Dataframe
result = df.merge(mesh, on='Col', how='left').fillna(0)
```

**Output**

```
  Col    n
0   x  1.0
1   x  2.0
2   y  5.0
3   y  6.0
4   y  7.0
5   z  0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Col':['x','y','z']})

arrays=[i for i in [[1,2],[5,6,7],[]]] #let me illustrate the arrays like this

df['newcol']=arrays


df.explode('newcol')
```